# struts2 web app is not working in tomcat7 insalled in susi linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, struts2, tomcat7

I have developed a web application based on struts2.2.1, using Eclipse indigo IDE with apache-tomcat-7.0.28. To make it work without IDE I have deployed it in Eclipse IDE using: right-click on the project->Export->war.

So, I get war file which I can able to make it work on any windows server installed with apache-tomcat-7.0.28, just copying the war file to tomcat's webapps folder and running the surver. Every things work fine here.

But, when I take this same war file to Linux server installed with same apache-tomcat-7.0.28, it is unable to open event the jsp file specified in web.xml and it shows error 404 page.

I even tried on different linux machines (like Ubuntu), but its not working and I get same 404 error.

why is it so?

**UPDATE:**

it took this form **catalina.out** file inside logs folder and inside

```
Jul 17, 2012 9:35:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/ai]
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/ai.war
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ai] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@626028]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@970110]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 17, 2012 9:36:56 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@1c6f1f4]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@36d036]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 17, 2012 9:38:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/GeneTest
Jul 17, 2012 10:21:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/ai]
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/ai.war
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ai] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@1c8e80d]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@fadb88]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jul 17, 2012 10:22:39 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/ai] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@162c87a]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@57f389]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ai</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**UPDATE: after upgrading form struts2.2.1 to struts2.3.4**

```
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib64/jvm/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 16 more
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8009
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:406)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:974)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
    ... 16 more
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 544 ms
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/ai3.war
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManager)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Overriding property struts.i18n.reload - old value: false new value: true
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger info
INFO: Overriding property struts.configuration.xml.reload - old value: false new value: true
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ai3] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/ROOT
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/docs
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/examples
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/host-manager
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/manager
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps/GeneTest
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 18, 2012 10:38:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2106 ms
```

Comment: A 404 error is only a signal the app was not loaded but the cause could be among many things. Try looking for more information in the Tomcat log files.

Comment: but what is the reason it works good in windows server?

Comment: Even if Java almost lives up to the promise of running the same on diverse systems, a web app can depend on many external things like Tomcat configuration, databases, security, etc.

Comment: any error/exception in the console/log file? more over see it through tomcat deploy manager if application has been deployed or not.Also make sure to scan server start-up log for any error/exception

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi @ madth3 I have updated my question with catalina.out and web.xml. I doubt it on why it show error on filterStart?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk seemms like server is getting some error on startup `SEVERE: Context [/ai] start up failed due to previous errors`. Can you just deploy application and do fresh installation

Comment: I believe same issue has been registered with S2 [JIRA-WW-3772](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3772) and has been resolved with version 2.2.3

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi so do you suggest me to switch to struts 2.2.3..?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: Yes please upgrade and see if the problem is still there? and if its there we can dig inside to see what is the root cause as it appears to me a known bug with `ContainerImpl` which was duly raised and has been fixed by community

Comment: OK, but whats the reason behind that it works good in windows server?.. this question make me to not accept your suggestion to upgrade to struts2.2.3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13981/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-k-k-and-umesh-awasthi)

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: new exception is not related to S2 as there seems some binding error with the port, seems like some other application/prog is already occupying the said port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFTER THE UPGRADATION This stacktrace shows the application port is already in use means the process is already running try to use different port for the application.or

before the upgradation:RUNTIME Classpath has duplicate TLD's you have to check below paths to 
 appserver's /lib folder or the JDK's /lib folder and then those check again  in the /WEB-INF/lib folder of the WAR build. remove the tld's from the webapps/lib folder if already there in the appservers/lib or JDK's/lib folder